# A facade root has not been set when writing pest test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

in my laravel app i have a simple http test that have written in pest

```
it('test http', function () {

    $post= [
            {some data}
        ];

    $expectedStatusCode = 200;

    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer {token}',
    ])->post({url}, $post);

    expect($response->status())->toBe($expectedStatusCode);
}
```

when i execute the code it return me this error
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Try using the [laravel plugin](https://pestphp.com/docs/plugins#laravel)